# DSUM formula in Excel Challenge not summing exact criteria but similar ones

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Got a problem when using DSUM in excel.

I got everything working great, but when investigating I realised that it is calculating multiple similar criteria together.

I.e.

Column C (Criteria3) has unique products like, D8, D9, D9+, D9+L.

If I have selected that the third criteria is D9, it sums all the products for D9, D9+ and D9+L.

How do I get it to only SUM the D9 items?

See comment for sample data, hope it is useful.

```
Selector Criteria 1 Criteria 2 Criteria 3 Sum 
------------------- ---------- ---------- --- 
A                   Value      D1         200 
A                   Value      D1         100 
B                   Result     A1         100 
A                   Value      D1+        100 
B                   Nothing    B1         100
```

I understand you can say i.e. ="=D9" but I am using in DSUM cell reference as I need it to be dynamic depending on my selected product combination.

Comment: Put some sample data and your formula, then explain what is going wrong.

Comment: Selector        
        
Criteria 1 Criteria 2 Criteria 3   Criteria 1 Criteria 2 Criteria 3 Sum
A Value D1 200  A Value D1 100
     B Result A1 100
     A Value D1+ 100
     B Nothing B1 100

Comment: Sorry new to this, not sure how I add excel format as example

Comment: @Jay - I've added your example to the question - do edit it in case it is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, so what I want is to have a selector that populates the "Criteria table" (this means each of my criterias will be a cell reference rather than the actual criteria. But I still want it to sum the exact product that my criteria reference is referring to... i.e. my criteria may be "=D1" (a cell) yet I want the functionality of the exact match that DSUM has ("="D1") example.

Comment: What is the `DSUM` formula that you're using currently?

Comment: In the example I use: =DSUM(G5:J10,4,B5:D6)
In the real one I use: =IFERROR(DSUM(RampU17,BG1,$BC$2:$BH$16),0)

Comment: My spontanious thought is that I need a macro that will change the cells in database cell by cell to instead of D1, D1+ etc... to auto change these to ="=D1", ="=D1+", etc... does this make sense? If so, what would that macro look like?

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working...

In the cells where it is getting the criteria from (which is a cell reference) I simply added the formula to add it in... i.e. ="="&(Cell Ref)

So if the cell refers to product D1 it gives the answer"=D1" in the cell. this solved the problem.